# Can not grab a body of code in JetBrains' GoLand

Tags: go, key, jetbrains-ide, goland

I installed latest version of GoLand. I want to grab a piece of code with <kbd>Shift + (up or down)</kbd> keys but I can't. It drives me crazy. Any solutions?

Comment: I guess it's using kind of vim tradition of typing but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. I installed Vim plugin as well while installing jetbrains goland. I just disabled it from settings/plugins/IdeaVim. Just unchecked IdeaVim.